# How much storage is this fio command utilizing?

Tags: command, jobs, kubernetes

I have a fio workload running as a Job.

Fio workload:

```
---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fio-target
spec:
  #storageClassName: ocs-storagecluster-cephfs
  storageClassName: ocs-storagecluster-ceph-rbd
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fio-config
data: 
  workload.fio: |
    [simple-write]
    readwrite=write
    buffered=1
    blocksize=4k
    ioengine=libaio
    directory=/target
    #size=10G
    fill_fs=1

---

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: fio
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: fio
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fio
          image: quay.io/johnstrunk/fs-performance:latest
          command:
            - "/usr/bin/fio"
            - "--output-format=json"
            - "/etc/fio/workload.fio"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: target
              mountPath: /target
            - name: fio-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/fio
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: target
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fio-target
        - name: fio-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: fio-config
```

Output of fio workload:

```
fio: io_u error on file /target/simple-write.0.0: No space left on device: write offset=52638969856, buflen=4096
{
  "fio version" : "fio-3.7",
  "timestamp" : 1578468421,
  "timestamp_ms" : 1578468421512,
  "time" : "Wed Jan  8 07:27:01 2020",
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "jobname" : "simple-write",
      "groupid" : 0,
      "error" : 0,
      "eta" : 0,
      "elapsed" : 149,
      "job options" : {
        "rw" : "write",
        "buffered" : "1",
        "bs" : "4k",
        "ioengine" : "libaio",
        "directory" : "/target",
        "fill_device" : "1"
      },
      "read" : {
        "io_bytes" : 0,
        "io_kbytes" : 0,
        "bw_bytes" : 0,
        "bw" : 0,
        "iops" : 0.000000,
        "runtime" : 0,
        "total_ios" : 0,
        "short_ios" : 0,
        "drop_ios" : 0,
        "slat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000
        },
        "clat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000,
          "percentile" : {
            "1.000000" : 0,
            "5.000000" : 0,
            "10.000000" : 0,
            "20.000000" : 0,
            "30.000000" : 0,
            "40.000000" : 0,
            "50.000000" : 0,
            "60.000000" : 0,
            "70.000000" : 0,
            "80.000000" : 0,
            "90.000000" : 0,
            "95.000000" : 0,
            "99.000000" : 0,
            "99.500000" : 0,
            "99.900000" : 0,
            "99.950000" : 0,
            "99.990000" : 0
          }
        },
        "lat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000
        },
        "bw_min" : 0,
        "bw_max" : 0,
        "bw_agg" : 0.000000,
        "bw_mean" : 0.000000,
        "bw_dev" : 0.000000,
        "bw_samples" : 0,
        "iops_min" : 0,
        "iops_max" : 0,
        "iops_mean" : 0.000000,
        "iops_stddev" : 0.000000,
        "iops_samples" : 0
      },
      "write" : {
        "io_bytes" : 52638969856,
        "io_kbytes" : 51405244,
        "bw_bytes" : 355971772,
        "bw" : 347628,
        "iops" : 86907.177732,
        "runtime" : 147874,
        "total_ios" : 12851312,
        "short_ios" : 0,
        "drop_ios" : 0,
        "slat_ns" : {
          "min" : 2123,
          "max" : 1877670923,
          "mean" : 10619.164491,
          "stddev" : 1295004.136689
        },
        "clat_ns" : {
          "min" : 559,
          "max" : 503883,
          "mean" : 597.424963,
          "stddev" : 334.725902,
          "percentile" : {
            "1.000000" : 572,
            "5.000000" : 572,
            "10.000000" : 572,
            "20.000000" : 580,
            "30.000000" : 580,
            "40.000000" : 580,
            "50.000000" : 580,
            "60.000000" : 588,
            "70.000000" : 588,
            "80.000000" : 588,
            "90.000000" : 596,
            "95.000000" : 604,
            "99.000000" : 780,
            "99.500000" : 868,
            "99.900000" : 1976,
            "99.950000" : 7392,
            "99.990000" : 11968
          }
        },
        "lat_ns" : {
          "min" : 2750,
          "max" : 1877675884,
          "mean" : 11260.353627,
          "stddev" : 1295013.364993
        },
        "bw_min" : 8,
        "bw_max" : 1046704,
        "bw_agg" : 100.000000,
        "bw_mean" : 369150.841727,
        "bw_dev" : 237962.484144,
        "bw_samples" : 278,
        "iops_min" : 2,
        "iops_max" : 261676,
        "iops_mean" : 92287.737410,
        "iops_stddev" : 59490.597358,
        "iops_samples" : 278
      },
      "trim" : {
        "io_bytes" : 0,
        "io_kbytes" : 0,
        "bw_bytes" : 0,
        "bw" : 0,
        "iops" : 0.000000,
        "runtime" : 0,
        "total_ios" : 0,
        "short_ios" : 0,
        "drop_ios" : 0,
        "slat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000
        },
        "clat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000,
          "percentile" : {
            "1.000000" : 0,
            "5.000000" : 0,
            "10.000000" : 0,
            "20.000000" : 0,
            "30.000000" : 0,
            "40.000000" : 0,
            "50.000000" : 0,
            "60.000000" : 0,
            "70.000000" : 0,
            "80.000000" : 0,
            "90.000000" : 0,
            "95.000000" : 0,
            "99.000000" : 0,
            "99.500000" : 0,
            "99.900000" : 0,
            "99.950000" : 0,
            "99.990000" : 0
          }
        },
        "lat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000
        },
        "bw_min" : 0,
        "bw_max" : 0,
        "bw_agg" : 0.000000,
        "bw_mean" : 0.000000,
        "bw_dev" : 0.000000,
        "bw_samples" : 0,
        "iops_min" : 0,
        "iops_max" : 0,
        "iops_mean" : 0.000000,
        "iops_stddev" : 0.000000,
        "iops_samples" : 0
      },
      "sync" : {
        "lat_ns" : {
          "min" : 0,
          "max" : 0,
          "mean" : 0.000000,
          "stddev" : 0.000000,
          "percentile" : {
            "1.000000" : 0,
            "5.000000" : 0,
            "10.000000" : 0,
            "20.000000" : 0,
            "30.000000" : 0,
            "40.000000" : 0,
            "50.000000" : 0,
            "60.000000" : 0,
            "70.000000" : 0,
            "80.000000" : 0,
            "90.000000" : 0,
            "95.000000" : 0,
            "99.000000" : 0,
            "99.500000" : 0,
            "99.900000" : 0,
            "99.950000" : 0,
            "99.990000" : 0
          }
        },
        "total_ios" : 0
      },
      "usr_cpu" : 8.353114,
      "sys_cpu" : 27.498597,
      "ctx" : 9500,
      "majf" : 0,
      "minf" : 20,
      "iodepth_level" : {
        "1" : 100.000000,
        "2" : 0.000000,
        "4" : 0.000000,
        "8" : 0.000000,
        "16" : 0.000000,
        "32" : 0.000000,
        ">=64" : 0.000000
      },
      "latency_ns" : {
        "2" : 0.000000,
        "4" : 0.000000,
        "10" : 0.000000,
        "20" : 0.000000,
        "50" : 0.000000,
        "100" : 0.000000,
        "250" : 0.000000,
        "500" : 0.000000,
        "750" : 98.191811,
        "1000" : 1.513962
      },
      "latency_us" : {
        "2" : 0.197637,
        "4" : 0.019383,
        "10" : 0.060476,
        "20" : 0.012987,
        "50" : 0.010000,
        "100" : 0.010000,
        "250" : 0.010000,
        "500" : 0.000000,
        "750" : 0.010000,
        "1000" : 0.000000
      },
      "latency_ms" : {
        "2" : 0.000000,
        "4" : 0.000000,
        "10" : 0.000000,
        "20" : 0.000000,
        "50" : 0.000000,
        "100" : 0.000000,
        "250" : 0.000000,
        "500" : 0.000000,
        "750" : 0.000000,
        "1000" : 0.000000,
        "2000" : 0.000000,
        ">=2000" : 0.000000
      },
      "latency_depth" : 1,
      "latency_target" : 0,
      "latency_percentile" : 100.000000,
      "latency_window" : 0
    }
  ],
  "disk_util" : [
    {
      "name" : "rbd0",
      "read_ios" : 35,
      "write_ios" : 9010,
      "read_merges" : 0,
      "write_merges" : 9085,
      "read_ticks" : 20979,
      "write_ticks" : 23182697,
      "in_queue" : 23199138,
      "util" : 5.652565
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot understand why this job is asking for more space ?
After this job got run I cannot see any fio PVC listed under "kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes" metric.

Also very weird to see storage used shoot to 148 GB from 0.4 GB on my cluster.

Can somebody explain this as far as I can understand it should be using 50GB only ?

Comment: [fio documentation](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this looks like you're using some sort of wrapper around fio (because [fio itself doesn't use YAML for its jobfile format](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#job-file-format)) which reduces the number of people who may be willing to look at this question... Having said that we can see what the true job parameters were thanks to you including the fio JSON output :-). Here's a key snippet:

```
      "job options" : {
        "rw" : "write",
        "buffered" : "1",
        "bs" : "4k",
        "ioengine" : "libaio",
        "directory" : "/target",
        "fill_device" : "1"
      },
```

So you are setting [`fill_device=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-fill-device) (by setting `fill_fs=1` which is an alias) which will try and grow a file until there's no space left and then start doing I/O on it. If that file isn't cleaned up I can see how future runs won't find any space available!

> How much storage is this fio command utilizing?

As much as it can!

> I cannot understand why this job is asking for more space ?

It asks for all the space because you told it to by setting `fill_fs=1`.

> Can somebody explain this as far as I can understand it should be using 50GB only ?

I cannot see why it should be limited to that - was there something in your config that references 50GB?

PS: The [`libaio` ioengine won't be asynchronous when you use buffered I/O](https://serverfault.com/a/918973/203726)...

Comment: actually its using 50Gi of storage attached as pvc